# CakePHP assocation question

Tags: cakephp

I'm creating a small timesheet application. Timesheets have athletes, and each athlete has personal split times (like in running, or race car driving)

An Athlete hasMany Run, a Run belongsTo Athlete, An Athlete hasAndBelongsToMany Timesheets (and vice versa). A Timesheet hasMany Run, and finally a Run belongsTo Timesheet.

When I'm adding new runs in my view, I'm unable to get anything but the athlete_id in the select box. I'd really like to have their names instead. Instead of

`<?php echo $run['athlete_id'];?>`, I've tried `<?php echo $athlete['Athlete']['last_name'] ?>` but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how you are building your forms/data it is hard to tell, but how I would do it is.

In the RunController add

```
$athletes = $this->Run->Athlete->find('list');
$this->set('athletes', $athletes);
```

and then in the View use this form helper line.

```
<?php echo $form->input('Run.athlete_id', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $athletes)); ?>
```

This should work, there is also a way to use 'compact' to make it a little easier but the above should work fine.

---- BEGIN EDIT ----

I did a little research and found the compact method.

In your RunController use

```
$athletes = $this->Run->Athlete->find('list');
$this->set(compact('athletes'));
```

and then in your View use

```
<?php echo $form->input('Run.athlete_id'); ?>
```

and the form helper will automatically find the compacted Athlete array and build the select.

---- END EDIT ----

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out the content of the $run: print_r($run) and see if the ['Athlete'] is there.

If not, you might have to manually contain the Athlete model when you do your run query:
$this->Run->contain('Athlete');

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use the displayField property of the Model class i.e.

```
<?php
    class Athlete extends AppModel {
        public $name = "Athlete";
        public $displayField = "name"; // the field name that has the athletes name in it
    }
?>
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/438/displayField